# How many outer **this** will have this inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have the following case of inner classes.

```
class Outer {
   private class Inner1 extends InnerBase {
   }
   private class Inner2 extends InnerBase {
   }
   private class InnerBase {
   }
}
```

Usually I considered an inner class to have an additional, hidden "this" to the outer class.

However, but what will happen is the inner class is derived from an other inner class?

All inner classes (Inner1, Inner2, InnerBase) should have an additional this.

Will Inner1, Inner2 have own references to outer this ?
Or just reusing the one from InnerBase, causing a slightly different behavior?

(Hidden this == a reference pointing to the instance of outer class)

Comment: As far as I am aware, ``this`` always points to the instance of the class you are in. There is no way (unless you make one) of accessing the parent class instance from the inner class instance. I'm not quite sure what you mean by a *"hidden this"*.

Comment: @Lattyware Each instance of a non-static nested class has a reference to the instance of its enclosing class which created it. That is also why you cannot instantiate non-static nested types within static methods. In the example, you can access this enclosing instance with: `Outer.this`

Comment: @stefanbachert Could you explain where the difference in behavior would be?

Comment: In the first case ANY inner class get an own hidden outer this (wasting somewhat memory), in the later only the first inner class gets an hidden outer this.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer How truly weird. I've never been a fan of Java's implicit ``this`` in the first place, I guess I'm used to Python's explicit ``self``. Well, one learns something new every day.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer Well, you CAN instantiate non-static nested types within static methods, you just need an outer instance to work with the strange outer-new syntax: `Outer o = new Outer(); Inner1 i1 = o.new Inner1();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally each non-static inner class in the hierarchy will have its own reference to `this`.  You can confirm it with `javap`

```
$ javap -private Outer.Inner1
Compiled from "Outer.java"
class Outer$Inner1 extends Outer$InnerBase{
    final Outer this$0;
    private Outer$Inner1(Outer);
}

$ javap -private Outer.InnerBase
Compiled from "Outer.java"
class Outer$InnerBase extends java.lang.Object{
    final Outer this$0;
    private Outer$InnerBase(Outer);
    Outer$InnerBase(Outer, Outer$1);
}
```

BTW, if you really want, you can exploit some obscure java syntax to have different values for the `this$0` member between the parent and child class.  Here's how:

```
public class Outer {
    class InnerBase {
        Outer innerBaseOuter() { return Outer.this; }
    }

    class Inner1 extends InnerBase {
        public Inner1() {}
        public Inner1(Outer parentOuter) {
            parentOuter.super(); // set a different super in InnerBase
        }
        Outer innerOuter() { return Outer.this; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer1 = new Outer();
        Outer outer2 = new Outer();

        Inner1 a = outer1.new Inner1();
        System.out.println("Checking (a.base == a.inner) => "+
            (a.innerBaseOuter() == a.innerOuter()));

        Inner1 b = outer1.new Inner1(outer2);
        System.out.println("Checking (b.base == b.inner) => "+
            (b.innerBaseOuter() == b.innerOuter()));
    }
}
```

Running the program you get:

```
Checking (a.base == a.inner) => true
Checking (b.base == b.inner) => false
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I am a bit confused, could you explain this a bit more? ^^

Comment: I wondered why InnerBase has two constructors. Then I found it: The second one is a synthetic constructor inserted by the compiler. The default constructor of a private class is private, but any Inner1 constructor must still call a non-private constructor of InnerBase. So a synthetic constructor is added with default visibility. The signature clash (both constructors need only the Outer reference) is resolved by adding another argument, of synthetic type Outer$1.

Comment: `javap -private` prints out all the members of a compiled class file.  When you compile an inner class, the compiler automatically adds an internal field called `this$0` to hold the containing class's "this" reference.  Not really magic if you think about it--the runtime system needs to store a reference to the containing classes instance, and the automatically generated member is how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Each will have a reference to the same instance of Outer.  They will each have their own reference to Outer, but that reference will point at the same instance of Outer.  Since the reference cannot be changed, referencing the Outer this from any of them would be equivalent.

```
class Outer {
    private class Inner1 extends InnerBase {
        Outer getOuter() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }

    private class Inner2 extends InnerBase {
        Outer getOuter() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }

    private class InnerBase {
        Outer getOuter() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().test();
    }
    public void test() {
        System.out.println((new Inner1()).getOuter());
        System.out.println((new Inner2()).getOuter());
        System.out.println((new InnerBase()).getOuter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at the program:

```
public class Outer 
{
    public Outer() {}
    class Inner1 extends Outer 
    {
        public Inner1() 
        {
            super(); // invokes Object() constructor
        }
    }

    class Inner2 extends Inner1 
    {
        public Inner2() 
        {
            super(); // invokes Inner1() constructor
        }
    }
}
```

An error would occur, if an attempt is made to compile it.

```
Outer.java:12: cannot reference this before
supertype constructor has been called
super(); // invokes Inner1() constructor
```

Because the superclass of `Inner2` is itself an inner class, an obscure language
rule comes into play. As you know, the instantiation of an inner class, such as
`Inner1`, requires an enclosing instance to be supplied to the constructor. Normally,
it is supplied implicitly, but it can also be supplied explicitly with a superclass
constructor invocation of the form `expression.super(args)`

If the enclosing instance is supplied implicitly, the compiler generates the expression:
It uses the this reference for the innermost enclosing class of which the
superclass is a member. This is, admittedly, quite a mouthful, but it is what the
compiler does. In this case, the superclass is `Inner1`. Because the current class,
`Inner2`, extends Outer indirectly, it has Inner1 as an inherited member. Therefore,
the qualifying expression for the superclass constructor is simply this. The
compiler supplies an enclosing instance, rewriting super to this.super.

The default `Inner2` constructor attempts to reference
`this` before the superclass constructor has been called, which is illegal.

The brute-force way to fix this problem is to provide the reasonable
enclosing instance explicitly:

```
public class Outer
{
    class Inner1 extends Outer { }
    class Inner2 extends Inner1 
    {
        public Inner2() 
        {
            Outer.this.super();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles, but it is complex. There is a better solution:
**Whenever you write a member class, ask yourself, Does this class really need
an enclosing instance? If the answer is no, make it static**. Inner classes are
sometimes useful, but they can easily introduce complications that make a program
difficult to understand. They have complex interactions with generics,
reflection, and inheritance. If you declare `Inner1` to be static, the problem goes
away. If you also declare `Inner2` to be static, you can actually understand what
the program does.

In summary, it is rarely appropriate for one class to be both an inner class and
a subclass of another. More generally, it is rarely appropriate to extend an inner
class; if you must, think long and hard about the enclosing instance. Most member classes can and should be declared static.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one level of "innering" in your example, so each inner class will have acces to the `Outer` class as you mention.

Here is an example for fun:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Level1 l1 = new Level1();
        Level1.Level2 l2 = l1.new Level2();
        Level1.Level2.Level3 l3 = l2.new Level3();
    }

    public static class Level1 {

        private String s = "Level1";

        public Level1() {
            System.out.println(this + ": " + s);
        }

        public class Level2 {

            private String s = "Level2";

            public Level2() {
                System.out.println(this + ": " + s);
                System.out.println("Level1: " + Level1.this);
            }

            public class Level3 extends OtherLevel {

                private String s = "Level3";

                public Level3() {
                    System.out.println(this + ": " + s);
                    System.out.println("Level1: " + Level1.this);
                    System.out.println("Level2: " + Level2.this);

                    System.out.println("super: " + super.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        public class OtherLevel {

            private String s = "OtherLevel";

            public OtherLevel() {
                System.out.println(this + ": " + s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
javaapplication4.Test$Level1@70284ac3: Level1
javaapplication4.Test$Level1$Level2@74a14fed: Level2
Level1: javaapplication4.Test$Level1@70284ac3
javaapplication4.Test$Level1$Level2$Level3@88d00c6: OtherLevel
javaapplication4.Test$Level1$Level2$Level3@88d00c6: Level3
Level1: javaapplication4.Test$Level1@70284ac3
Level2: javaapplication4.Test$Level1$Level2@74a14fed
super: javaapplication4.Test$Level1$Level2$Level3@88d00c6
```